# replacing a menu for new one from another method on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

First sorry if the title is not the best to explain my problem.
I am trying to do a kind of login where you click on a 'new account' button and then disappear the login buttons made on **init** method and appear stuffs from createaccount method.

I did this. I tried doing grid_forget() pack_forget() and I am not able to do it yet.
I am working with python 3.
Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
class Login:
    def __init__(self, ventana):
        ventana.title("Login - Python")
        ventana.geometry("800x600")
        Label(ventana, text="name: ").grid(column=0, row=0)
        Label(ventana, text="Password: ").grid(column=0, row=1)
        Button(ventana, text="Login").grid(column=0, row=2)
        Button(ventana, text="Create Account", command=self.createaccount).grid(column=0, row=3)
        Button(ventana, text="Exit").grid(column=0, row=4) 
    def createaccount(self):
        print("createaccount method executed")
        Label(ventana, text="Name: ").grid(column=2, row=0)
        Label(ventana, text="Password: ").grid(column=2, row=1)
        Label(ventana, text="Repeat Password: ").grid(column=2, row=2)
        Label(ventana, text="Email: ").grid(column=2, row=3)
        Label(ventana, text="Repeat E-mail: ").grid(column=2, row=4)

ventana = Tk()
objeto=Login(ventana)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your widgets later in your program you need to store them in a variable.

```
def __init__(self, ventana):
    ventana.title("Login - Python")
    ventana.geometry("800x600")
    self.lblName = Label(ventana, text="name: ")
    self.lblPass = Label(ventana, text="Password: ")
    .....
    .....
    self.lblName.grid(column=0, row=0)
    self.lblPass.grid(column=0, row=1)
    .....
    .....
```

Now you can use those widgets any place in your code.

```
 def createaccount(self):
    self.lblName.grid_forget()
    self.lblPass.grid_forget() 
    #and so on...
```

Note that, creation of a widget and placing them with `grid` are on seperate lines.

Comment: p.s. I think this question is not dupe of NoneType error because this one missing variable usage in first place. Hence I answered it. If you think question is dupe, feel free to ping me so I can delete this answer.